# Angular-Datables incrementing watchers indefinately each refresh until browser crash

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am fairly new to AngularJS and therefore, I guess I don't totally understand how certain things work.

However, I have implemented an Angular-Datatable which populates 279 records. On each record (row) I show a selectable checkbox as per the online documentation, but what I am finding when I run performance testing is that Angular sets up watchers for each row.  I also have my page on a 1 minute timer which rebuilds the datatable through a `.reloadData()` call.

My code to build the columns...

```
$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('').notSortable()
            .renderWith(function(data, type, row, meta) {
                $scope.selected[row.dev_id] = $scope.selectAll;
                return '<input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleOne(selected)" ng-model="selected[' + data.dev_id + ']" ng-cloak />';
            }).withClass("text-center"),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('dev_id').withTitle('ID'),
    ...
```

... causes the '# of watchers' to increment by 558 each minute (shown below) until my browser eventually crashes out with a low memory error.

[image]

It seems to be the `ng-model="selected[' + data.dev_id + ']"` in my `dtColumns` that is causing the issue.

Do I need to be clearing something on each refresh?

I am using Chrome.

Comment: Sorry to bring up this post again, but I'm experiencing the same problem. What did you do to solve the problem?

Comment: @JurgenVandw I haven't looked at this for sometime and my angular experience was quite new when I posted this.  However, in short I removed the auto refresh and added a manual refresh button for now.  I may go back and look at this again at some stage when I get the chance.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help right now.